# Is it possible to have a secondary dimension in Google Analytics app?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to set a report in Google Analytics app with the first dimension is `Source`, and the second dimension is `Page title`. It seems that the app does not support secondary dimension. I have an idea to create [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en), but then the app doesn't seem to allow that as well. Is it correct that there is no way for me to achieve that?